# How to simulate a spinning helicopter rotor visual effect programatically?

Tags: graphics, graphic-effects

I decided to display an animation that conveys to the viewer that a narrow flat surface is spinning really fast(such as an helicopter's rotor blade). Does anyone have any experience in implementing this effect and could provide an implementation?
Please remember a rotor on video looks different than it does in real life.
I need to make the rotor look like it does in real life and not on video.

Comment: Duplicate? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3326/how-to-do-this-sprite-motion-blur

Comment: @Byte56 I don't think the glowing blue is suitable for a helicopter blade. The effect speeder asked for is of an object spinning at much slower rates.

Answer (score 5):

The way I've always done it is simply to create a pre-blurred version of the texture, something like [this image](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/rob.neal2/misc/Helicopter%20Blades.jpg), map it on a circle, and draw it using alpha blending.  Make the circle spin pretty fast and you're done.